Flutter: Tabbarview - is it a bad idea to dispose it often
I have a Tabbarview in my app, and I have many error states, that must hide tab bars, tab content, etc - everything related to tabs. How bad is it to switch between these views constantly? Should I preserve (not dispose) Tabbarview for all costs for the sake of cpu and responsiveness?

Did you ever try overlayEntry ?

Use a Stack to overlay error messages or loading indicators on top of the TabBarView. This way, the TabBarView remains in the widget tree but is visually obscured.
 Stack(
       children: [
           TabBarView(
               // ... your tab bar view content
           ),
           if (errorState) ErrorOverlay()
       ],
   )

